# How can I set up my SQL so that a delete on a parent deletes child rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [TestId]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]        NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestQuestion] (
    [TestId]         INT      NOT NULL,
    [TestQuestionId] INT      NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]    CHAR (6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestId] ASC, [TestQuestionId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TestQuestionTest] FOREIGN KEY ([TestId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Test] ([TestId])
);
```

Is there a way I can make this so that when I delete a row in the Test table then all rows with that TestId are deleted from the TestQuestion table?

Comment: Look up `cascade delete`

Comment: Use a cascade delete - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2743/using-delete-cascade-option-for-foreign-keys/

Comment: Look at : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620086/CASCADE-in-SQL-Server-with-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just provide `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your Foreign Key of `Child Table`(`TestQuestion.TestId`), so it will delete child record directly when parent record is deleted.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
        [TestId]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [Title]        NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestId] ASC)
    );

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestQuestion] (
        [TestId]         INT      NOT NULL,
        [TestQuestionId] INT      NOT NULL,
        [QuestionUId]    CHAR (6) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_TestQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestId] ASC, [TestQuestionId] ASC),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_TestQuestionTest] FOREIGN KEY ([TestId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Test] ([TestId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
```

Actually you can have many option with `DELETE` (and `UPDATE` also) like:

.

**For Delete**

```
ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }
```

.

**For Update**

```
ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }
```

Answer (score 0):

As other commentators have said, the cascading foreign key is the best way to go.  If you need more complicated logic, however, you could use a FOR DELETE trigger.